How to configure Rate Limit for Next.js SG build
The Next.js application we built requires building about 20 million pages of static screens.
We need to fetch an external API for each of those screens, which by default requires 10,000 requests per minute per build to the API server.
Besides scaling up the API server, is it possible to change the request rate at build time in the Next.js build settings?
Next version is 14.
